# Need some advice writing a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view with columns [Date], [ProductId], [NewProduct]. Where [Date] is always [yyyy-mm-01], so for a given month, [NewProduct] can either be 1 or 0 for any productId. 
I am trying to create another view based on this one but I want to implement one change. If a product has been marked as [NewProduct] for a given month then it should be marked as a [NewProduct] for the remaining months of that year.

Example This is my original view: ProductView1

[image: ProductView1]

As you can see product: 261220 is marked as new product for 2018-05-01.
What I want is I want to create another view derived from this view which should have product: 261220 marked as new product for the rest of the 2018.

I am trying to write a query like this:

```
 CREATE View [dbo].[ProductView2]
As
    SELECT  [ProductView1].[Date]
            ,[ProductView1].[ProductId]
            ,Case WHEN ([ProductView1Prev].[New Product] = 1 AND Month([ProductView1Prev].[Date]) <> 12) 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE [ProductView1].[New Product] 
            END AS [New Product]
    FROM    [dbo].[ProductView1]
    left join
            [ProductView1] as [ProductView1Prev]
            ON [ProductView1].CustomerId = [ProductView1Prev].CustomerId
    and     [ProductView1].[Date] = dateadd(month,+1,[ProductView1Prev].[Date])
```

But the new view Mark product: 261220 as a new product for the next month rather than all the remaining months for that year.

ProductView2 looks like this based on my query:

[image: ProductView2]

I am not sure how to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Which SQL format are you using?  Can you show the query used to create your original view?

Comment: I am using sql server 2017.

Answer (score 0):

try using a "trigger after update"  with checking conditions (month bigger than this month by where clause) and check if this column updated then update other columns as well.